# What is the best CentOS 6 repo list for LAMP stacks?

Tags: package-management, yum

I'm just getting into server administration and now everybody needs something. Lately I'm getting stuck on package hunting, so I'm on the search to find the most comprehensive repo list of LAMP packages.

What repositories do you use in your list for LAMP resources and why do you use them?

Comment: There is only one "LAMP" stack: Linux, Apache, MySQL, {Perl,Python,PHP}. This comes with CentOS, in the standard repository. You must mean something different, so if you could edit your post to clarify what it is you are looking for instead...?

Comment: Switch to a rolling release distribution for the server, such as Arch Linux or Gentoo, if you want up to date, bleeding edge software.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean other stuff besides apache, mysql and p(hp/erl/ython).  I use:

http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/39

I have a hard time finding stuff that I need that isn't in one of these.

Answer (score 1):

At work we use modified RPMs from the [IUS repo](http://iuscommunity.org/). The repo is meant to be used in conjunction with the EPEL repo from Fedora. We use it because:

- You have control over which version of PHP and/or MySQL your server will follow, there are no surprise upgrades. With other repos I've followed over the years, you can get a surprise upgrade in major PHP versions (like from 5.3 to 5.4) when the maintainer decides to upgrade their PHP version. This is undesirable since your software might not be fully tested on the latest PHP or you have legacy software that depends on an older PHP version. With IUS, it requires active work on your part to upgrade major PHP versions. If you set your server up to follow the PHP 5.3 line, it will follow the PHP 5.3 line but you will never get a surprise upgrade to PHP 5.4. The same thing goes for MySQL.
- Upgrading and downgrading is simple: `yum replace php --replace-with php53u`
- It works with/depends on EPEL which is another well planned repo that does not conflict or upgrade stock RHEL/CentOS RPMs.
- It has been around for a while. I've seen many other people set up repos for various PHP and MySQL versions, but the maintainer runs out of steam after a few months and the repo stagnates. You're then left to either your own copy of the repo or you have to hunt around for a new repo.

IUS provides PHP and MySQL mostly. For python on el5, we pull in the python26 package from EPEL which is installed alongside the version provided by CentOS.

And to answer the part of your question about a list of repos that provide LAMP, here you go:

- [IUS](http://iuscommunity.org/)
- [Remi](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/) with instructions [here](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) (he contributes to Fedora's PHP RPMs too)
- [Atomic](http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/)
- [Webtatic](http://www.webtatic.com/)